# Regex temperature validation

Tags: regex, validation, laravel-4

How will the temperature validation in regex be ? The temperature could be both integer and decimal but not text. I am not setting any limits of how many digits, simple as it could be both integer and decimal.

This is the regex for XX,XX format:

```
'regex:/[\d]{2},[\d]{2}/'
```

Comment: Some examples that show what you want to match and what not would help

Comment: `regex:/\d+(,\d+)?/` can help you

Comment: With that I can use . with regex:/\d+(,\d+)?/ how can I only allow comma if it's decimal and not . ?

Comment: @user3185936 Can you clarify your last comment with input sample please?

Comment: I was able to input 23,23 in my database with that regex and that is fine. But I am also able to input 23.23 which I dont want. How can I change the regex to not to accept (.)

Comment: @user3185936 Change to `regex:/^\d+(,\d+)?$/`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, it matches XX and XX,XX for any number of digits on either side of `','`:

`'regex:/[\d]*,?[\d]*/'`

Optionally, you can do this for the units as well: `(132.0 C) or (32.0000 F) or (32. K)`

`'regex:/[\d]*,?[\d]* [CFK]/'`